# How to add a custom field in ALM 12.5 at the Test Folder level in Test plan

Tags: alm

I need to have separate template at each folder level ,not at project level.
Lets say in details tab I have 10 fields in one folder and I need only fields in another folder in the same project.
Please let me know if this is possible with Workflow or any other way.

Thanks,
Ms

Answer (score 1):

In HPALM, test folder is not part of entity structure framework. Hence you won't be able to setup custom fields at this level. Workflow customization will not help here.